# C# Kannada Language Support In Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, kannada

I have a Label in my Form and it's text was written in English using Segoe UI as font. Then I changed my font to Baraha Kan for Kannada translation and also changed my Form's Language from Default to Kannada(India).

But this way only some characters got translated. I can still see English alphabets in the words.

How do I translate the English to Kannada Completely?

Comment: You have 2 resource files for yourform, one for English(yourform.resx) and second for Kannada(yourform.kn.resx). Look at the second ones content, find `yourlabel.Text' in Name column. What is in value of that record? If it is incorrect, try to change to correct one there. Also when you change language you also need to change everything manually - it will not auto-translate contents of controls.

Comment: Baraha Kan is not a Unicode compatible font, it uses ASCII codes for its glyphs.  So this mishap is expected, you need to use [another font](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Kannada.html).